# loop all gridview rows on button click when paging enabled

Tags: .net, gridview

I have paging enabled in my gridview...

I need this in button click event

1. gridview total row count
2. loop through all the rows in foreach

but it's only working for the current gridview page...help

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] no = new int[GridView2.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {            
        Label l = (Label)row.FindControl("Label2");
        if (l.Text == "Unpaid")
        {
            int productID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
            no[i] = productID;
            i++;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to achieve you have to disable paging before loop. rebind the grid & perform loop .
Then enable paging & bind the grid again.

```
       protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
 { 
GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
 // do your databind here 
GridView2.databind(); 
int[] no = new int[GridView2.Rows.Count];      
          int i = 0;        
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)      
      {                             
   Label l = (Label)row.FindControl("Label2");
                    if (l.Text == "Unpaid")        
            {                    
    int productID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);                        no[i] = productID;                        i++;                    }                }  


              )



GridView2.AllowPaging = true;
        // do your databind here again
        GridView2.databind();
```