# Remember the check-box option in a GridView while paging and looping through entire GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have a `gridview` on a `aspx` page with pagination enabled. this `gridview` contains some data fields from a database and a `check-box` for each row.

[image: COD Pagination]

Now, I read on this post: [loop all gridview rows on button click when paging enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706466/loop-all-gridview-rows-on-button-click-when-paging-enabled) that to be able to loop through all the rows on all the pages of the `gridview`, I have to disable the pagination, rebind the `gridview`, loop through all rows, re-enable the pagination and finally rebind the gridview.

I started out wondering whether the check-box option will be remembered if I rebind the `datasource` before looping through all the rows, but quickly determined that even going from one page to the next page then back again the `check-box` option is lost.

I need to have a `gridview` with pagination and a `check-box` on each row, then loop through the entire `gridview` on the click of a button and do some action depending on the `check-box` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible with the GridView natively. But there are many methods to simulate the same behaviour. One method will be to handle the issue on the PageIndexChanging event like this.

```
protected void OriginalTable_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedIDs = (Session["CheckedIDs"] != null) ? 
        Session["CheckedIDs"] as List<int> : new List<int>();

    //we are now at current page. set the checked ids to a list
    foreach (GridViewRow row in OriginalTable.Rows)
    {
        //get the checkbox in the row ( "HasEmail" is the name of the asp:CheckBox )
        var emailCheckBox = row.FindControl("HasEmail") as CheckBox;
        //gets the primary key of the corresponding row
        var rowOrgID = Convert.ToInt32(OriginalTable.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
        //is row org_id in the selectedIDs list
        var isRowIDPresentInList = selectedIDs.Contains(rowOrgID);
        // add to list
        if (emailCheckBox.Checked && !isRowIDPresentInList)
        {
            selectedIDs.Add(rowOrgID);
        }
        //remove from list
        if (!emailCheckBox.Checked && isRowIDPresentInList)
        {
            selectedIDs.Remove(rowOrgID);
        }
    }
    OriginalTable.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindTable();
    //we are now at the new page after paging
    //get the select ids and make the gridview checkbox checked accordingly
    foreach (GridViewRow row in OriginalTable.Rows)
    {
        var emailCheckBox = row.FindControl("HasEmail") as CheckBox;
        var rowOrgID = Convert.ToInt32(OriginalTable.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
        if (selectedIDs.Contains(rowOrgID))
        {
            emailCheckBox.Checked = true;
        }
    }
    Session["CheckedIDs"] = (selectedIDs.Count > 0) ? selectedIDs : null;
}
```

Here we are using `Session` to maintain the values across pages. As an added advantage you will get the checked values in any other event by accessing the session variable.

---

**Update**
If you already have pre-populated HasEmail field, do this to set the values at initialization

```
private void BindTable()
{
    DataTable table = GetTableFromDatabase();

    var selectedIDs = table.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<bool>("HasEmail"))
        .Select(r => r.Field<int>("ORG_ID"))
        .ToList();
    if (selectedIDs != null && selectedIDs.Count > 0)
        Session["CheckedIDs"] = selectedIDs;

    OriginalTable.DataSource = table;
    OriginalTable.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I will have to work on it a bit to get it down. Thanks

Comment: If I think about it for a bit: The ID's of the rows where the check-box is true is stored in the `Session`? And removed if a check-box is unchecked? This happens only when a page is changed, so on the click of the button I need to go through the open page and do the same adding/removing, then loop through the id's in the `Session`? And before that, I need to add all of the items of all the pages to the list in the `Session` for if the user doesn't visit all the pages. So have all selected by default, and remove and potentially re-add as the user go's through the pages. If I've got it straight?

Comment: It's not that there is a `HasEmail` field in the database. The check-box is just used for a decision: send an email to this address or don't send an email to this address. Basically, its a recipient selector and by default all the recipients are selected.

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this solution successfully. I did notice that I had to explicitly save the list to the session at the end of `OriginalTable_PageIndexChanging`. E.g.: 

`Session["CheckedIds"] = selectedEmails;`

Also, I had to figure out at some point when to clear the session, otherwise the previous run's values stays in the session variable.